# How can I create a legend without a plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

This is for an art project. I've created a scatterplot with many dots of 5 different colours. I want to create a legend that is completely separate from the plot, as in it is not on the plot, nor beside the plot, but is in it's own window so I can save the legend as it's own .pdf file. This is so I can have my plot and legend printed separately as they well be hung in a gallery as separate pieces.

All I want is to recreate this image using R:

[image]

Is this even possible?

Thanks,

Jay

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sure.  Just start from an empty plot and then use legend as you would if there were a plot.

```
plot(NULL ,xaxt='n',yaxt='n',bty='n',ylab='',xlab='', xlim=0:1, ylim=0:1)
legend("topleft", legend =c('Sugar maple', 'White ash', 'Black walnut',
    'Red oak', 'Eastern hemlock'), pch=16, pt.cex=3, cex=1.5, bty='n',
    col = c('orange', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple'))
mtext("Species", at=0.2, cex=2)
```

[image: Legend without a plot]

Comment: Wow I never thought of that. Plot the legend on an empty plot, so simple haha. Thank you VERY much G5W :)

Comment: @G5W can you make the list two rows?

Comment: @sar  Yes.  Just add the argument `ncol=2` to the legend statement.

Comment: @G5W I have 19 variables but it cuts off the last 3 variables when in one column. Why would this be?

Comment: @sar  I can't say without more information.  I suggest that you ask a new question. Please post your code so that we can see what is happening.  It might be a good idea to mention that your question is a follow-up to this question.