# How to create a stand alone legend in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

This is a slightly different but very similar question to [How can i create a legend without a plot in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966645/how-can-i-create-a-legend-without-a-plot-in-r) but differs in that I do not want to use the -pch- option in -plot( )- but rather I would like to create legend that represents different time series plots overlaid. What I am trying to create is:

[image]

The above legend is created using -ggplot( )- but I am creating 6 plots that have identical legends and want to suppress the legends and create a stand-alone legend that represents all. I cannot just create an array of plots in R, the coordinator of the project I am working on insists I create separate plots and try to make a separate legend so this is my work around.

Currently I have adapted the linked question from above and created this:

```
legend <- plot(NULL ,xaxt='n',yaxt='n',bty='n',ylab='',xlab='', xlim=0:1, ylim=0:1)
legend("topleft", legend =c('Africa', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'North America', 'Oceania', "South America"), pch=16, pt.cex=7, cex=1.5, bty='n',
    col = c('orange', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple'))
mtext("Continent", at=0.2, cex=2)
legend
```

[image]

And the colours do not match up, although I am sure I can update them on my own after getting some help on the main issue.

I suppose my overall question is how am I supposed to do this? I looked through all of the values for the option -pch=" "- but they are all just symbols so I am unsure where to go from here.

Comment: Have you seen the [**cowplot** article](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/shared_legends.html) on shared legends for ggplot2 plots?  That seems like it'd really help you do what you want to do.

Comment: That is a very useful article thank you for sharing it! I would regularly do something similar; however, I ideally need to create a separate image for the legend as we are manually placing it in a word document next to the images of the plots for a research paper. If this isn't possible (I think it must be) then I will definitely use the -cowplot- function and just create an array of the plots!

Comment: You can capture the legend as shown in the article and then plot only the legend with `plot_grid()` or `ggdraw()` so you can save it with `ggsave()` (with appropriate height/width for such a small plot).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is closer to what you want. Don't plot symbols if you want lines. Read the manual page for `legend()`. It is confusing, but there are many options. Basic graphics is different from ggplot and they do not mesh easily.

```
names <- c('Africa', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'North America', 'Oceania',
             'South America')
clrs <- c('orange', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple')
ltype <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1)
plot(NULL ,xaxt='n',yaxt='n',bty='n',ylab='',xlab='', xlim=0:1, ylim=0:1)
legend("topleft", title="Continent", legend = names, lty=ltype, lwd=2, cex=1.25,
       bty='n', col = clrs)
```

[image: Legend]

Comment: How would you make one of these dashed?

Comment: See the updated answer. Just make a vector for line types.

Comment: that code looks good, except that it's bad practice to reuse 'names' as the name of the vector of names, since 'names' is already a core function in R